# Why won't this div autoscroll?

Tags: jquery, ajax, autoscroll

I've got this working nicely, but the autoscroll refuses to work... any idea why?

PS I only want to use jQuery... `commentsList` is inside of `commentsPanel`

```
    $.ajax({
            url: 'comments.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            success: function (comments_html) {

                $('#commentsPanel').html(comments_html);
                var commentsList = document.getElementById('#commentsList');
                commentsList.scrollTop = commentsList.scrollHeight;
                $('#loading').hide();
            }
        });
```

Thanks!

```
   <div id="commentsPanel">
    <table width="260" height="220" border="0" cellpadding="3">
                    <tr><td height="5"></td><td><span style="text-align:right;"><a href="#close" rel="close_comment">Close</tr>
                    <tr><td height="220" valign="top">
                        <div id="commentsList" style="overflow: auto; width: 260px; height: 220px; text-align=left">
    <!-- CONTENT -->

    </div>
                </td></tr>
                <tr><td height="50">
                <form id="new_comment" name="comment_form" method="post" action="comments.php">
                    <input type="hidden" id="trackID" value="' . $track . '">
                    <input type="text" size="25" id="new_comment_text" /><span style="text-align:right">
                    <input type="submit" value="Comment" id="submit_comment"/></span>
                </form>
                </td></tr>
                </table>
</div>
```

Comment: 1: where is the markup? 2: what browsers/versions are you trying to make it work in?

Comment: The HTML you have posted is invalid. Fix the indentation and you'll see what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/NJv6w/

Answer (score 2):

When using `var commentsList = document.getElementById('#commentsList');` you dont need to include the `#`

```
var commentsList = document.getElementById('commentsList');
```

Comment: What is your intended result after the `ajax complete`?  Since you are destorying the `commentsPanel` by calling `.html()` where in the scrollable div do you want the view?  It should be at top by default, but if not you can simply do `commentsList.scrollTop = 0`?

Answer (score 1):

Funny, you said: *"I only want to use jQuery"* and yet you use `document.getElementById()`.

You're mixing up jQuery with DOM methods. Change this line:

```
var commentsList = document.getElementById('#commentsList');
```

to this:

```
var commentsList = $('#commentsList');
```

Comment: I just meant, I don't want to use a plugin.

Comment: I did try both answers here, and it doesn't seem to be working (yet)

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'comments.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            success: function (comments_html) {

                $('#commentsPanel').html(comments_html);
                var commentsList = $('#commentsList'); //<- changed
                commentsList.scrollTop(commentsList.scrollHeight()); //<- add brackets here
                $('#loading').hide();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You say that `commentsList` is *inside* `commentsPanel` but you are replacing everything inside `commentsPanel` with this line:

```
$('#commentsPanel').html(comments_html);
```

Are you sure that `commentsList` actually exists at the time? Add the following after your `var commentsList = ...` line.

```
console.log(commentsList);
```

To make sure that it actually exists.